# Coffee machine strategy pattern implementation

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, strategy, strategy-pattern

I came across an article about LSP https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/ . It seems that a strategy pattern could be implemented here but I cannot see how to implement it.

My idea is to let the brewCoffee be the strategy method, in which i state what kind of coffee should be brewed. The following is an overview over the design,[image]

Here's my solution so far:
[image]

BasicCoffeeMachine should only be able to brew filter coffee, while PremiumCoffeeMachine should be able to brew both filter and espresso. But as of yet, both machines can do both. Should i introduce another interface, one being for BasicCoffeeMachine and one for PremiumCoffeeMachine?

Any feedback overall?

How would you implement the strategy pattern in this case?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73627635/implementing-strategy-pattern "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: okay i deleted it. I would highly appreaciate if you could atleast give some feedback. Thanks in advance

Comment: The CoffeeMachine hierarchy (prior to your introduction of BrewEspresso and BrewFilterCoffee) *is already* the Strategy pattern. CoffeeMachine plays the role of the abstract strategy interface, while Premium and Basic represent concrete strategies. A client would get injected with one or the other, and it would call the brewCoffee virtual method at some point. Now, with your addition, if you want BasicCoffeeMachine to only be able to brew filter coffee, change its constructor to accept a BrewFilterCoffee parameter (rather than IStrategy).

Comment: So if i understand it correct, the design is complete and follows the strategy pattern - and I only need to change the constructor of BasicCoffeeMachine to only accept brewFilterCoffee? Sorry my english is not good. Thanks!

Comment: What I'm saying is that the original design in the article was already created in a way that allows it to be used like the Strategy pattern by the calling code. You then added your IStrategy (and its derivatives) on top of that, so now you essentially have two instances of the Strategy pattern, one using the other (which may be an overkill in this case, but generally speaking is something that can be done (it's not "wrong") - depends on what you're trying to do).1/2

Comment: Now, in terms of design, by accepting an IStrategy as a constructor parameter (without any constraints), you're communicating to the user (the developer using your class) that *any* derivative of IStrategy is fine. By constraining to BrewFilterCoffee, you're preventing BasicCoffeeMachine from participating in the strategy pattern (the one you added, rooted in IStrategy), meaning that it now cannot take any IStrategy, but only BrewFilterCoffee (and its derivatives, if there are any) - which is what you wanted. 2/2

Comment: P.S. One problem with this (in terms of what I'm suggesting) that Christophe noticed and I didn't at first, is that your CoffeeMachine base class also has a reference to IStrategy, and this is then inherited by the derived classes. This is probably not necessary, unless there must be some shared logic in CoffeeMachine - logic using IStrategy - that must be inherited by Premium and Basic. If that's not the case, that's unnecessary coupling that limits your flexibility, so try to remove any reference to IStrategy from CoffeeMachine, and just have IStrategy be used by PremiumCoffeeMachine only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second diagram, the `PremiumCoffeeMachine` and the `BasicCoffeMachine` both inherit the composite aggregation of their generalization `CoffeeMachine` with `IStrategy`.

The way you modelled the diagram is without any specific constraint.  So any `IStrategy` could be used with any `CoffeeMachine`.  If this is too flexible, you have several choices:

- Introduce a distinction between different families of `IStrategy` and associate them only with the appropriate family of coffee machines.
- Redefine/Subset the association of specific coffee machine with specific strategies.
- Simply express the constraint in regarding the associated types.  This is more flexible in the model.

Whatever your choice,  the fact that a subclass contraints the usable strategies, i.e.  strengthen the pre-conditions,  the design will not be LSP compliant.

Other unrelated remarks:  there is no need to repeat the composite aggregation of `CoffeeMachine` for all its specializations: the specialized machines inherit the associations from their ancestors (by the way, the arrow head of inheritance should be hollow,  i.e a large white triangle).

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice at first that CoffeeMachine references IStrategy (I left a comment under the question earlier). Looks like the OP is doing this for practice, but depending on the requirements in an real-world scenario, another option (as an alternative to your last paragraph) would be to actually remove that, and (if possible) let the derivatives decide if they are going to use IStrategy or not. BTW, I think the (second) diagram is auto-generated from code by an IDE, so I'm not sure that it follows UML conventions 100% (it's probably more of a visualization of what references what).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Thanks for these insights. Indeed, letting the derivates decide if IStrategy is to be used or prefer some specific subtype of IStrategy, is what I meant in the first bullet

Answer (score 0):

You can have a property "canMakeExpresso" which each class implements. And the method "makeExpresso" throws an error / exception if you call it for a class that doesn't implement it.

You decide if you want a property "canMakeRegularCoffee" which returns true for all existing classes - and a method "makeRegularCoffee" which is always implemented.

Now these two properties are properties of the coffee machine that you don't expect to change while the coffee machine is plugged in. You could also check if the coffee machine has water, has the right ground coffee or coffee beans etc. which you would assume to change at runtime. I'd keep those separate. So "canMakeExpresso" would return true even if the machine has no water.